# Mail forwarding

Tags: email, mail-forwarding

I have domain for example: example.com, I registered it, then i create dns record in zoneedit.com When i ping example.com, it's ping 127.0.0.1 it's ok.

Then i create mail forwarding from user@exmaple.com to existing mail adress in gmail.com, When i try to send message to user@example.com, nothing messages in gmail adress.

Why?

Thank you.

Comment: Which operating system? Which MTA? How is it configured? What's in your logs?

Comment: What DNS record did you create in ZoneEdit?  Why is the DNS pointing to the 127.0.0.1 IP?

Answer (score 0):

127.0.0.1 is a loopback address that only allows one machine to talk to itself, nothing else. In order to run with the big dogs and exchange mail between other smtp systems you will need a "hard" or world routable IP address. You probably have one and are just using the wrong address. If you are behind a firewall you will also need forwarding and such straightened out.

Additionally pinging a domain only tests one kind of DNS record: the A record; you also need to check that you set the MX record correctly since this is what mail servers use to identify who handles mail for a domain.